# How to convert a big list of dictionaries into a pandas dataframe of this format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a big list of dictionaries that can be put into either one of two below formats:

```
[{'cqug90j': [0, 1]},
 {'cqug90k': [7, 10]},
 {'cqug90z': [-3, 0]},
 {'cqug91c': [2, 9]}]
    
[{'cqug90j': {0, 1}},
 {'cqug90k': {7, 10}},
 {'cqug90z': {-3, 0}},
 {'cqug91c': {2, 9}}]
```

I need to convert into a pandas dataframe

[image]

My list contains 4 millions of such dictionaries.  Could you please elaborate on an efficient way to obtain my desired dataframe?

**Update:** My list can also be put into the below form.

```
[{'cqug90j': {'var1': 0, 'var2': 1}},
 {'cqug90k': {'var1': 7, 'var2': 10}},
 {'cqug90z': {'var1': -3, 'var2': 0}},
 {'cqug91c': {'var1': 2, 'var2': 9}}]
```

Comment: Sets are unordered. You can't guarantee which comes in `var1` which in `var2` if you have `{'cqug90j': {0, 1}}`, unless you mean to sort the values.

Comment: @QuangHoang So I have no choice but `{'cqug90j': [0, 1]}` ^^.

Comment: @LEAnhDung--do you want the smaller to always go in var1 and larger into var2?  This is the pattern in your example, but does it hold in general? If True, then it provides a predictable way to handle sets.

Comment: @DarrylG Sadly, my list does not have such property.

Comment: @QuangHoang I also update a possible format of the list. Please see if it can improve the speed.

Comment: @DarrylG I've updated a possible format of the list. Please see if it can improve the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to preprocess your data to get it in the correct form.
A dictionary where the keys are your column names and the values your variables.

```
data = [
    dict(id='cqug90j', var1=0, var2=1),
    dict(id='cqug90k', var1=7, var2=10)
    ...
    ...
]
```

Then you can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)`.
Even for millions of values this should still only take a few seconds to process.

#### Example

- Generating an arbitrary number of samples in your (first) specified format:

```
def generate_data(size=4_000_000):
    data = []
    iterator = product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', repeat=6)

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    while len(data) < size:
        data.append({''.join(next(iterator)): [np.random.randint(-256, 256), np.random.randint(-256, 256)]})
    print(f"Generated: {len(data):,d} items in {time.perf_counter() - start_time:5.2f}s")
    return data
```

`This would take about ~30 seconds on my laptop.`

- Preprocessing the data to get them in a nice form

```
def reprocess(data):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    data = [dict(id=key, var1=var1, var2=var2) for dictionary in data for key, (var1, var2) in dictionary.items()]
    print(f"Reprocessed: {len(data):,d} items in {time.perf_counter() - start_time:5.2f}s")
    return data
```

The interesting line is:

```
data = [dict(id=key, var1=var1, var2=var2) for dictionary in data for key, (var1, var2) in dictionary.items()]
```

which is a list comprehension equal to:

```
data = []
for dictionary in data:
    for key, (var1, var2) in dictionary.items():
        data.append(dict(id=key, var1=var1, var2=var2))
```

`Time taken about 2 seconds.`

- Generating the panda dataframe

```
def generate_dataframe(data):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    print(f"Generate df: {len(df):,d} items in {time.perf_counter() - start_time:5.2f}s")
    return df
```

`Which takes about 5 seconds on my device.`

Full code run

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = generate_data(size=4_000_000)
    data = reprocess(data)
    df = generate_dataframe(data)
    print(f"\n{df.head()}", end="\n\n")
```

And output:

```
Generated: 4,000,000 items in 30.75s
Reprocessed: 4,000,000 items in  1.47s
Generate df: 4,000,000 items in  3.70s

       id  var1  var2
0  aaaaaa   173  -191
1  aaaaab   238   -60
2  aaaaac   -59   -25
3  aaaaad  -225   236
4  aaaaae   137   -18
```

#### Conclusion

The total time taken for changing 4 million items to a dataframe is about 6 seconds. I am not sure if you need it to be much faster. But I think this is a good start.

Answer (score 2):

For huge data, I'd use a generator:

```
l = [
    {"cqug90j": {"var1": 0, "var2": 1}},
    {"cqug90k": {"var1": 7, "var2": 10}},
    {"cqug90z": {"var1": -3, "var2": 0}},
    {"cqug91c": {"var1": 2, "var2": 9}},
]


def get_data(l):
    for d in l:
        k, d2 = d.popitem()
        yield k, d2["var1"], d2["var2"]


df = pd.DataFrame(get_data(l), columns=["id", "var1", "var2"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        id  var1  var2
0  cqug90j     0     1
1  cqug90k     7    10
2  cqug90z    -3     0
3  cqug91c     2     9
```